# Require Node.js modules using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the node.js for visual studio extension to recognize my npm modules. Here's what  I currenly have :

```
import http = require('http');
import brain = require('brain');

var port = process.env.port || 1337


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end(train());
}).listen(port);

var train = function () {
   var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

   net.train([{ input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
       { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
       { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
       { input: [1, 1], output: [0] }]);

       var output = net.run([1, 0]);  // [0.987]
       return output;
 }
```

I have the [brain](https://github.com/harthur/brain) library installed using the built in npm modules installer inside Visual Studio 2013.
The npm module installer comes from the [Node.js tools for Visual studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/).

The problem is whenever I run the application I get the following error :

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'brain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nikolay\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projec
s\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1\server.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Is it possible that if you run it from the command line with node server.js, it would work?  I would bet that VS cannot find the module for some reason.

Comment: Just used the : node server.ts command

Output is http://pastebin.com/tgARwEJ4

Comment: I don't think your require syntax is correct.  Try var http = require('http'); var brain = require(brain);

Comment: Using node server.js (not ts) successfully launched my server. Does this mean that the module is properly installed?

Comment: If it starts, yes.  Not sure what the .ts extension is.

Comment: That's the typescript extension, but it seems that there's a backing .js file in there. Hmm that's odd it seems that for some reason Visual studio doesn't retrieve the metadata from the module to provide intellisense.

Comment: Please don't post images of code if not necessary. It's difficult to read, and a lot more difficult to search for. Extract the text and show the errors in a block comment for instance.

Comment: @Patrick fully modified the question to match the conventions.